# In next.js, not-found.tsx works fine in dev, but it doesn't work when building

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I made not-found.tsx to prepare for 404 errors, but if I type URL incorrectly, dev gives me a built page, but when I build and test, I give you a 404 error page that comes by default from next.js

I've looked it up on the next.js official site as well, but I couldn't find it. Looking at the built folder, I see that 404 pages are not downloading properly, so I don't think not-found.tsx is recognized.